# Ngrx Data GetAll and modify path

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-ngrx-data, ngrx-data

I am completely new to Ngrx Data and am trying to modify the url for a get request. So I have a Roles app that provides a manager the ability to give users roles and am needing to retrieve all of the user permissions based on application id and employee id.

For this portion of the app, I am needing to call an http get request like https://localhost/AppAccess/UserPermissions/{appId}/{employeeId}  (i.e. https://localhost/AppAccess/UserPermissions/11/2903).

How can I get ngrx data to call this?  So far getAll cannot take a url so I can't add my route params. getByKey throws a warning for selectId is meant to return a single record, and getWithQuery uses query parameters.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To override urls you need to implement your own `HttpUrlGenerator` and provide it in providers: https://ngrx.io/api/data/HttpUrlGenerator

```js
abstract class HttpUrlGenerator {
  abstract entityResource(entityName: string, root: string): string
  abstract collectionResource(entityName: string, root: string): string
  abstract registerHttpResourceUrls(entityHttpResourceUrls?: EntityHttpResourceUrls): void
}
```